# How do you save MLGazeteer meta-data... is there a bug?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have successfully created an MLGazetteer, but when I create metadata to be saved along with the mlmodel, it doesn't seem to save.  Here is how I am saving the meta-data:

```
    let parameters = MLGazetteer.ModelParameters(language: .english)
    let gazetteer = try! MLGazetteer(dictionary: xyzdict, parameters: parameters)
    let metadata = MLModelMetadata(author: "My Name", shortDescription: "This is my Gazetteer", license: nil, version: "1.0", additional: nil)
    try gazetteer.write(toFile: "xyz.mlmodel", metadata: metadata)
```

Like I said, the model saves correctly and I am able to use it in my project.  But if you click on the mlmodel file within Xcode, it shows

```
Author: unknown
Description: This model is a gazetteer which tags words according to set {...}
License: unknown
```

This obviously isn't a big deal, since it is working properly, but still, it's annoying enough that I wanted to see if anyone else has seen this in their projects.